# Compatibility between GCC and LLVM

Tags: gcc, llvm, abi

I'm working on a project that is cross platform, and on OS X one section must be built with clang/llvm because it creates a Cocoa window, the rest of the project is built with GCC.  This is compiled into a static library which is linked into the main executable.  For example

```
//printnum.h
std::pair<uint32_t, uint32_t> printnum(int num);

//printnum.mm
#include "printnum.h"
#include <stdio.h>

std::pair<uint32_t, uint32_t> printnum(int num)
{
    printf("%d\n", num);
    //..... Objective C Code.....
}

//main.cpp
#include "printnum.h"

int main()
{
    printnum(0);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm using CMake to generate a makefile.  I've tried several different sets of compiler flags `-fPIC` etc.  But I get values printed like 1835455280, 1746993968, 1648001840.  Shouldn't the two compilers be binary compatible?  If I make the function void, then it works just fine.

Comment: I don't know about LLVM, but for C++ even different major versions of GCC are not always binary compatible. I think you have to back a while to have a problem though.

Comment: Sounds likes a bug. Please file a problem report in LLVM's bugzilla.

Answer (score 1):

Different compilers use different strategies for returning structures by value. One common technique is to internally rewrite this:

```
struct retval func(int a)
```

...as this:

```
void func(struct retval* retval, int a)
```

However, small structures can be returned in registers. A `std::pair<int, int>` is only 8 bytes, which means it counts as small in this context.

What I suspect's happening is that one compiler is doing the first and the second is doing the latter. Which means they're not matching.

Is this wrong? Dunno. I know that clang's libstdc++ is *not* binary interoperable with gcc's. But in your environment both compilers are probably seeing the same library (you might want to verify this). My understanding is that C++ binary compatibility between compilers is generally reckoned  not to be possible in the real world, though. But it might be theoretically possible.